# Passing Python Class to CLI arguments

Tags: design-patterns, python

So i want to make a crawler in python but not the usual UA/middlewares way.
My idea was a modulable architecture, which pass the callable class as arguments in a cli. This is kind of odd, i don't know if there any other way/framework which implement that.

Architecture detail:

I have a class Command which is pass with fire.Fire for the moment for the argument parsing with options more the class i want to use to build the crawler. I pass urls and others options to the Fetcher using a map, maybe replace by a partial after. Which then flow to Parser, scorer, store etc.. using their result.

The design i'm using for passing Class as args is the following:

I have a ABC class for example FetcherABC which maintain a registry of subclasses. Each fetchers inherits from FetcherABC and are in the same folder with an **init**.py who import them using an **all**

fetcher/default_fetcher.py

```
import FetcherABC
__all__ = [DefaultFetcher]

class DefaultFetcher(FetcherABC):
    pass
```

fetcher/**init**.py

```
from .default_fetcher.py import *
from .json_fetcher.py import *
__all__= (default_fetcher.__all__ + json_fetcher.__all__)
```

command.py

```
from repo.fetcher import *
from repo.fetcher.fetcherabc import FetcherABC

class Command:
   def __init__(self, urls, ... , fetcher):
       self._fetcher = fetcher

   @fetcher.setter(self, name: str):
       list_fetcher = [f.strip('.')[-1] for f in FetcherABC.__subclasses__()]
       if name in list_fetcher:
           self.fetcher = exec(name)
```

As i told before, maybe there others ways to do it, in that case, it would be a pleasure to know. The concern of how it could be use as a library is a point that i really want to know. Is this could be viable? Do i watch too much David Beazley those days? (probably).

Comment: are you trying to create a plugin system? I'm not entirely sure if I understand what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: As i said i want the crawler to be the more modulable possible. I can see that as a plugin system in some way. Passing class to the CLI will change the behavior of the crawler, ie a JsonFetcher, taking only json file found. Or PageRankScorer, different from GeneticScorer as it would implement PageRank instead of a genetic algorithm, both outputting a score with the same format